# How to show progressbar like recyclerView

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to show a progressbar like the one below (which i just saw in recyclerView)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check this it will solve your problem

```
android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        // put your layout here

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And activity code would be

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {
            refreshContent();
          ...
  }
```

Comment: hello，but  i don't need the recyclerview, i just need the progressbar in that style